# How to replace specific value by other values in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

I havew `ObservableCOllection`. I have a column there which is called `Name`. I want to replace all values for items where value is `"John"` to `"John Doe"` and all values where value is`"Anette"` to `"Anette Doe"`. How can i do so?

```
_users = new ObservableCollection<UserReadModel>(_userQuery.GetUsers().ToList());
```

Comment: Have you tried `Where` and `foreach` ? If so can you explain why that is not suitable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach for this is to iterate over the collection on the values you want to change, and then change it

```
foreach (var item in _users.Where(x => x.Name == "John" || x.Name == "Anette"))
{
    item.Name = $"{item.Name} Doe";
}
```

If you are planning to add more names to the list, i would recommend you doing something else such as adding some logic like with a list of possible Names, and use the Any method. But this would be reasonable if the values might change, in which case you could make a list and iterate over with the any on the list